# Is there an easier way to add CJK support to Kile?

Tags: fonts, latex, internationalization, chinese, kile

I am new to Kile and LaTeX and have already installed Kile and TeX Live 2012 on Ubuntu 12.04-LTS(64bits).

I feel like adding Chinese support following procedure provided by this website using CJK: [CJK Support](http://kile.sourceforge.net/Documentation/html/cjk.html).

However, I am stuck at Step 5,because I could not find the command `ttf2pfb` anywhere,though I have googled a long time.

I also want to install several Adobe fonts such as
 - AdobeFangsongStd-Regular (v5.010).otf
 - AdobeKaitiStd-Regular (v5.010).otf 
 - AdobeHeitiStd-Regular.otf
 - AdobeSongStd-Light.otf.

Hence I have two questions:

1. Is there an easier way to add Chinese support, if not, where I can find `ttf2pfb`?
2. Where I should place those Adobe fonts and how to let Kile and LaTeX recognize them and how to use this fonts?

I am going to appreciate it very much if there are some suggestions. and the more specific, the better.